# Fetch only the lines having doller sign at the beggning

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a file which has `$` at the begging, i just want to fetch these lines ony from the file.

### Below is my file.

## cat test_file

```
$ oc adm groups new dev-group
group.user.openshift.io/dev-group created
4.2. Add the developer user to dev-group.
$ oc adm groups add-users dev-group developer
group.user.openshift.io/dev-group added: "developer"
4.3. Create a second group called qa-group.
$ oc adm groups new qa-group
group.user.openshift.io/qa-group created
4.4. Add the qa-engineer user to qa-group.
$ oc adm groups add-users qa-group qa-engineer
group.user.openshift.io/qa-group added: "qa-engineer"
```

### What i tried:

```
# cat test_file | grep "(\$\w+)\[(\w*[a-z]\w*)\]"

and 

# cat test_file | grep '\$\$\$'
```

### Expected:

```
$ oc adm groups new dev-group
$ oc adm groups add-users dev-group developer
$ oc adm groups new qa-group
$ oc adm groups add-users qa-group qa-engineer
```

I googled around the given solution did not worked for me, i'm running on the ubuntu 14

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in form of code, could you please do add expected sample output too for clarity in your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Thank you , i have just updated the desired output.

Comment: isn't it as simple as ```grep '^[$]' myFile```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^\$/' file
```

Also `sed`:

```
$ sed -ne '/^\$/p' file
```

Or `grep`:

```
$ grep '^\$' file
```

Notes:

1. All three use the same [BRE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) of the anchor `^` indicating start of a line and `\$` meaning a literal `$`
2. Since `$` is a regex metacharacter meaning end of line, it needs to be escaped, `\$`, or you can use a character class to make it literal `[$]`
3. The regex of `/^$/` with an unescaped `$` would be the regex for a blank line since `^` means the start of a line and `$` means the end of a line.
4. You do not need to use `cat` as input to `sed`, `awk`, or `grep`. Each is able to read the file directly and that is usually preferred over catting the file. (See [Useless Use Of Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat))

Comment: Alternative for sed  `sed '/^\$/!d' file`

Comment: @potong: yup, or `sed  '/^[^$]/d' file` works too. I was trying to make all three regex's the same for `awk` `sed` or `grep`

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the lines that start with a `$`, just add the `^` that indicates the beginning of the line then the escaped dollar:

```sh
cat test_file | grep  '^\$'
```

Comment: Any reason you need a ```cat```? [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: No special need for a `cat`, I've just followed OP's way to do (I've personally tested with `grep  '^\$' test_file`)